# SQL - How to change primary key

Tags: sql

I have deleted two rows from my SQL table and the ID of the first row is now 3. how can I fix it? (Note: I don`t have more rows).

Comment: what is your DBMS?

Comment: Do you have any foreign keys pointing to this record? i.e. records in other tables that reference this primary key?

Comment: This is not a problem.  Hence, it does not need to be fixed.   Primary keys identify a row not only within a table but also throughout time.  Changing the primary key for a row is to be highly, highly discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

it is no problem generally.

But if you want you can set ID=1 for 3-rd row:

```
UPDATE TABLE tname SET id=1 WHERE id=3;
```

And update your primary key to 2:

```
ALTER TABLE tname AUTO_INCREMENT = 2;
```

Than new inserted row will have id=2.